# How do I launch Call of Duty 4/PEZBot with bots always enabled?

Tags: macos, call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

I have Call of Duty 4 (App Store version) on Mac, and PeZBOT mod for bots. I installed PeZBOT following the instructions to my Library folder, and it is working fine. However, by default, it does not have bots. Whenever I start a server, I must go to console and type

```
/svr_pezbots 6
```

(or whatever other number) to turn bots on. This is a bit tedious - how do I turn the bots on by default? I tried modifying pezbot.cfg in the mod folder, but it does not seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

The bots will be in for 2 or 3 matches after each other no quitting the match to start a new server. But after a while they will appear to be spectators.. I don't know why. But just try inserting new bots. If you want change maps use `/devmap mp_(and the maps name)`. For example, `/devmap mp_crossfire` will take you to that map and the bots will sometimes appear in the game. Also try `/set svr_pezbots` instead of just `/svr_pezbots`